# JQuery Is not working properly on mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Hi I am making an effect that is when Mouse Enter in div one button shows in that div and when user mouse leave that area again button hide.
It works but the problem is that I have used div many times so I have used class for div definition.
So when Mouse enter in one div other div also affected.

Code :

jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#container").mouseenter(function(){
    $(":button").show();
  });
  $("#container").mouseleave(function(){
    $(":button").hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

jsp code :

```
   <div id="container">
<div class="mainitemlist">
<div class="mainitemlistimage">
<a href="product?pid=3">
<img src="product_images/Tulips1760331818.jpg" height="125px" width="100px" style="border-radius:2px;">
</a>
</div>
<div class="mainitemlistname"><div align="center"><a href="product?pid=3" style="color: #9caeb9;text-decoration: none;">Nokia Lumia 925</a></div></div>
<div class="mainitemlistprice"><div align="center">38000</div></div>
<div class="mainitemlistfeatures"><div align="center">null</div>
<button type="button" style="display: none;">Hide me</button></div>
</div>

<div class="mainitemlist">
<div class="mainitemlistimage">
<a href="product?pid=5">
<img src="product_images/Jellyfish456319058.jpg" height="125px" width="100px" style="border-radius:2px;">
</a>
</div>
<div class="mainitemlistname"><div align="center"><a href="product?pid=5" style="color: #9caeb9;text-decoration: none;">HCL Me</a></div></div>
<div class="mainitemlistprice"><div align="center">40000</div></div>
<div class="mainitemlistfeatures"><div align="center">null</div>
<button type="button" style="display: none;">Hide me</button></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have try to put Jquery on `class="mainitemlist"` but It's not working.
So I have added in `id="container"`.
Anyone have idea, why it's not working ???

Comment: it works in chrome, maybe i am missing something? Can you please add jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mainitemlist").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find(":button").show();
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find(":button").hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dY2Xn/)

When you used the class `mainitemlist` you were not using the function scope properly using `$(this)` and hence it showing all the button on `mouseenter`, since you used the code:

```
$(":button").show();
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.mainitemlist', function () {
        $(this).find(":button").show();
    }).on('mouseleave', '.mainitemlist', function () {
        $(this).find(":button").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: on .mainitemlist it's not working. So I have added again in #container then also it;'s show effect for each item not for single item.

Comment: @user2659972 But it seems to be working the fiddle demo I have provide. Is it working for you too??

Comment: Yes that fiddle demo working for me also but I have not display data static it's dynamic from database and used Java Script for to sort data and also display data in JavaScript function that's why I think problem occurs.

Comment: Simply Great Great Great..  It's Done.. It's Completely Work.. Thank You SO Much Sir..

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#container").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#container button").show();
  });
  $("#container").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#container button").hide();
  });
});
```

check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNCWc/).

b.t.w, you have 2 divs with the id of `container`. this is probably a mistake, and if not, it's bad practice.

hope that helps.

Comment: I want to add Jquery on `class="mainitemlist"` but it's not working.And I have edited my question, by mistake I have added 2 `container`.

Comment: just replace `#container` in my code to `.mainitemlist`. i added a fiddle as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('#yourbutton').show();
});
$("#container").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('#yourbutton').hide();
});
```